# What's actually wrong with my XML?

Tags: xml, firefox, browser, safari

I have an automatically generated XML file for the game that I run. It however apparently has an error.

The file is at: http://woarl.com/myXML.xml

And the error is apparently at line 520, here are lines 519-521

```
<type>Academy</type>
<typeid>23</typeid>
<completion>4</completion>
```

Any ideas as to what the error is?

Comment: What actual error did you actually get?  What tool is rejecting the XML?

Comment: What actual error did you actually get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is incomplete.

When downloaded through the browser, it ends not like you shown, but like this:

```
<city> 
    <id>8</id> 
    <name>Breisgau</name> 
    <xpos>58</xpos> 
    <ypos>934</ypos> 
    <continent>Rayti</continent> 
    <continentid>3</continentid> 
    <size>52297</size> 
    <port>0</port> 
    <walled>1</walled> 
    <building> 
        <type>Academy</type>
```

That's it, the last `<type>` line there is line 518.

Comment: Ahh, for some reason the full file wasn't uploaded. How bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

The file you linked to ends right at line 520.  There is no typeid 23 and completion 4.

Perhaps your web server is doing something stupid.